# Control decimals per variable in summary table

Tags: stata

I am trying to get a summary table in Stata using the *community-contibuted* command `estout`.

However, I want to specify the number of decimals displayed per *variable*  as opposed to the default which is per summary statistic.

As you can see in my code below, I know how to control the decimals for a summary statistic as a whole (e.g. the mean is displayed with no decimals):

```
* Summary statistics

eststo clear
estpost tabstat length weight, stat(mean median sd min max n) columns(statistics)

esttab using summstat1.rtf, cells("mean(label(Mean) fmt(2)) p50(label(Median) 
fmt(0)) sd(label(ST. Dev) fmt(2)) min(label(Min) fmt(2)) max(label(Max) fmt(2)) 
count(label(N) fmt(0))") label title("Summary Statistics") nonumbers lines noobs replace
```

What I want specifically is the following:

- the `length` variable to be of the format `175` (i.e. no decimals)
- the `weight` variable to be formatted such as `60.545` (i.e. three decimals)

Of course, I could try to scale my variables by dividing or multiplying times a factor `10`, but this is not my problem and it something not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *each* summary statistic within the `cells()` option you can specify *multiple* formats.

Consider the following simplified example for `mean`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear

estpost tabstat mpg price length weight, stat(mean) columns(statistics)

esttab, cells("mean(label(Mean) fmt(0 3 5 1))") 
        label title("Summary Statistics") ///
        nonumbers lines noobs 

Summary Statistics
---------------------------------

                             Mean
---------------------------------
Mileage (mpg)                  21
Price                    6165.257
Length (in.)            187.93243
Weight (lbs.)              3019.5
---------------------------------
```